# How to marshall struct parameter byRef, when importing C DLL into C# console application?

Tags: c#, c, import, marshalling, dllimport

I am importing a C DLL into my C# program and have to marshall a ByRef struct parameter.

Here is the signature of the function in C:

```
extern "C" {
int __stdcall FuncToImport(const char* stringToMarshall, StructFromDLL* structToMarshall);
...
...
...
}
```

Here is how I tried to import it in C#

```
[DllImport("ImportedDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern IntPtr FuncToImport(string stringToImport, ref HandleRef structToImport);
```

When calling this in Main I get an exception:
*System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: '"parameter #7" cannot be marshalled: HandleRefs cannot be marshalled as ByRef or not managed/managed Parameter..'*

What would be a possible way to marshall the parameters properly?

Comment: HandleRef was a very mysterious choice.  You need to declare that struct in your C# code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
[DllImport("ImportedDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern IntPtr FuncToImport(string stringToImport, IntPtr structToImport);

private static IntPtr StructToPointer<T>(T Struct) where T : struct
{
    //Allocates the necessary memoryspace and creates a pointer to this memory
    int rawsize = Marshal.SizeOf(Struct);
    IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawsize);

    //Writes the current data from the struct to the allocated memory
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(Struct, pointer, false);

    return pointer;
}

private static T PointerToStruct<T>(IntPtr pointer) where T : struct
{
    //Creates a Struct of the type of T from the pointed memory
    T Struct = Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(pointer);
    //Frees the allocated memory
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointer);
    return Struct;
}

IntPtr pointer = StructToPointer(structToImport);

FuncToImport("", pointer);

structToImport = PointerToStruct<Type of structToImport>(pointer);
```

Comment: If the marshaler can't do marshal a struct automatically with the struct passed by `ref`, then this will also fail. Actual problem in the Q relates to the (mis)use of `HandleRef`.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about I do that all the time. You just have to define the same struct in C# and C. I am not marshaling a struct here I just give the C DLL a pointer to a byte[] which I still can read ones the C DLL Function is done.

Comment: Yes, but the asker did not define the struct, and that's the actual problem. And there's not point in doing all this manual marshaling with `IntPtr` when you can just do `ref StructFromDLL value` in the pinvoke parameter declaration.

Comment: I know that that is the actual problem but I wanted to give him a working solution, not just an explanation of what is wrong especially because someone already pointed that out. However, after testing it I must admit that my solution, although working, is unnecessarily complicated. I didn't know that you can use complex variables like structs directly. You live and learn.